# Mushin - Enormous improve state of controlled subconscious mind

Tags: consciousness

> Mushin in Japanese and Wuxin in Chinese (無心 "no mind") is a mental
> state. Zen and Daoist meditators attempt to reach this state, as well
> as artists and trained martial artists. They also practice this mental
> state during everyday activities.

[Mushin in Martial arts](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/13506/mushin-%E7%84%A1%E5%BF%83-no-mind-is-a-truth/13510#13510)

> The above passage now seems to be a clear description of the
> autonomous dorsal visuomotor module. However, without the explanation
> of science behind it, it seems unintelligible and impossible to
> understand.

[Neuroscience research from Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350636819_Mushin_in_Martial_Arts_and_Insights_from_Neuroscience)

Can today's science able to explain the state of Mushin ? The current information just seems like a pseudo-science.